# An unorthodox way to find cardinalities?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, set-theory

Let $\mathfrak{c}$ denote the cardinality of the continuum. I sketch an intuitive but non-rigorous argument that $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| = \mathfrak{c}$, with the question:

**Question**: can this argument be made rigorous?

---

**Sketch "proof"**: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, a \in \mathbb{R}$. It is a standard result that $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff:

1. $\forall\varepsilon>0 \; \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $|x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|  < \varepsilon$
2. $\forall (x_n)$ s.t. $x_n \to a$, $f(x_n) \to f(a)$

(1) requires something to be true for every element of a set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, while (2) requires something to be true for every element of:

$$S := \{(x_n) | x_n \to a\}$$

But since (1) and (2) are equivalent, we may deduce that $|S| = \mathfrak{c}$. It follows that $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| = \mathfrak{c}$.

(This argument has inaccuracies, at least some of which can be fixed with observations made below.)

---

**General idea**: If two logical statements are equivalent and each "depends"(?) on sets of cardinality $C$ and $C'$ respectively, then we would expect that $C = C'$.

I outline two potential issues that I spotted with this type of reasoning below.

---

**Objection A**: Suppose we let $T$ = $\{S\}$ i.e a set with $S$ as an element. Then, we can rephrase (2) as:

3. For every $s \in t$ of every $t \in T$, $f(s) \to f(a)$ (where $f(s)$ is interpreted in the obvious way).

But then $T$ is a set of cardinality $1$, and there's an issue because  $\mathfrak{c} \neq 1$. I think this issue could be remedied with a more rigorous approach, but I don't know any of the set theory which I expect is needed to do so.

---

**Objection B**: Consider the following two statements. We have that $x \le 0$ iff:

4. $x \le a$, $\; \forall a \in A_1$ where $A_1 = \{0\}$
5. $x \le a$, $\; \forall a \in A_2$ where $A_2 = \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$

Then, (4),(5) are equivalent, but depend on sets of wildly different cardinalities $1 \neq \mathfrak{c}$ again.

The solution to this is a bit more obvious. It is clear that most of $A_2$ is redundant, so we could argue that it has "effective cardinality" $1$, since it suffices to know simply whether or not $x \le a$ for $a=0 \in A_2$. But that doesn't solve the issue of (6):

6. $x < a$, $\; \forall a \in A_3$ where $A_3 = \mathbb{R}^+$

which is also equivalent to (4),(5) but appears to have countably infinite "effective cardinality". (Notably, $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not closed; I think that is key here.)

---

I expect that for both (A) and (B), there would need to be some kind of condition on what "types" of elements are allowed for the sets in question, and also the types of sets allowed.

Is there a way to reconcile all of these issues and make this a valid direction of argument? Is there any truth to the general idea described above, and if not, is there a clear error that can be pinpointed?

Comment: There is a quantifier missing in the second definition using sequences: the impkication must hold for **all** sequences converging to $a$.

Comment: I don't think your argument that the two sets must be equinumerous works, precisely for the reason you outline in Objection B. Your solution to B is completely ad hoc, and based on knowledge that you bring in from outside the argument itself. You have no warrant for making that assertion in the original argument. For another example, consider the statement "$a\leq b\iff \forall \epsilon\gt 0, a\lt b+\epsilon$" vs. "$a\leq b\iff \forall q\in\mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0}, a\lt b+q$". Arguing that the first collection is "redundant" requires knowledge of the density of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To the voter for closing this question. I would appreciate knowing what further context or details I should provide.

Comment: So in order to make your argument work, you would need to argue somehow that neither of your sets is "essentially redundant", which seems rather difficult to do with regards to your set $S$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree to some extent. In the question, I gave perhaps too informal a description. Maybe I could rephrase it as: the "effective cardinality" is the minimal cardinality of a subset such that the deductive closure of that subset (e.g. in ZFC?) is the entire set. So we may not be able to determine the effective cardinality, but it will exist. Also, I think it is not too difficult to argue that $S$ has effective cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$ (although certainly it has redundant elements).

Comment: Your argument is basically "all apples have this property iff all bananas have a _that_ related but subtly different properly, therefore there are equally many apples & bananas so the apple-facts can impose precisely the same constraints as the banana-facts". It's hard enough to prove the "number of degrees of freedom" in a problem is unique where finite, let alone where uncountable.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, that is essentially my argument. Please could you provide some examples (perhaps in an answer) of showing the uniqueness of degrees of freedom, and maybe instances where uniqueness does not hold, assuming they exist? I didn't realise it was a difficult problem in general.

Comment: Well, to take a simple example: on reals, $x$ exceeds all non-positive reals iff $x$ exceeds all non-positive integers.

Comment: @J.G. I meant in the finite case, since I already discussed a similar example in Objection B, and I don't think it's impossible that either objection could be fixed.

Comment: An interesting idea, but/and naturally needs lots of details! :)

Comment: My point is that even setting aside the issue of a precise definition of "effective cardinality" that allows you to prove things with it, your argument would have to establish that your set $S$ is equinumeros with any subset of $S$ with that satisfies whatever that definition happens to be; and that will probably/almost certainly be difficult and require even *more* information about real numbers to be brought to bear (if not essentially proving what you are trying to prove in the first place, given the nature of $S$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, just to clarify, I would not need to establish that $S$ and any such subset are equinumerous; I would only work with the effective cardinality, ignoring whatever the cardinality of $S$ actually is. (Similarly, it is only the effective cardinality of the set in (1) which is needed; it is not immediately clear what the set for (1) is, but I believe it has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.) It is true that in this case, completing such a proof takes more work than a standard proof but I gave this as an example of a technique that could optimistically be applied more generally.

Comment: OK: on integers, $x$ exceeds all even primes iff $x$ exceeds both elements of $\{0,\,2\}$.

Comment: @J.G. The effective cardinality of both sets is $1$. I already discussed this type of idea in Objection B. What were you referring to when talking about instances when it is difficult to show the number of degrees of freedom is finite?

Comment: I don't think that programme would get the conclusion you want! You are trying to show that $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}|$. Even if you show that your set $S$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$ have the same "effective cardinality", how does that get you the desired conclusion? You need to use the fact that $|S|=|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}|$, so you need to use that whatever the "effective cardinality" of $S$ may be, it is the same as the cardinality of $S$. Otherwise, you never get to your desired conclusion.

Comment: But this is all moot anyway, because you do **not** have anything approaching a non-ad-hoc way of talking about "effective cardinality". "I know it when I see it" may work for the Supreme Court when you are trying to determine if something is obscene, but it doesn't really fly for mathematical proofs.

Comment: Let me explain what you've done here. You've written a broken proof, asked us if it works, received answers as to why it doesn't, then invented arbitrary constraints on the format responses are allowed to take. That's not how maths works. You're supposed to prove to us that, if a certain condition holds, sets will be equipollent. You can't just expect an "explanation" to exist for why every hypothetical inferential rule isn't right.

Comment: FWIW the actual way to prove $\beth^{\aleph_0}=\beth$ is to apply $\kappa\mapsto2^\kappa$ to $\aleph_0^2=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're absolutely right, I missed that. It does not then give the desired conclusion, but I thought it did when I first wrote the question. So absolutely, I am now happy to concede then the proof fails for what it was designed. However, I still genuinely do not understand what was "non-ad-hoc" or poorly defined about effective cardinality, which is what I thought was your objection to the proof.

Comment: @legionwhale: "ad hoc" means "to this" meaning that it is an explanation suited for the specific case, and not in general. All your examples determine redundancy based on the specific situation, not based on any general principles; your attempt at a definition ("deductive closure") does not work for your purposes. You have examples in which a particular infinite set has "effective cardinality" which is finite. But one can deduce that an infinite set is not finite, and that a finite set is not infinite, so the two sets cannot have the same "deductive closure in ZF". (cont)

Comment: (cont) As such, while you have written down something that looks like a definition, it does not actually define the concept that you are trying to define. Thus, you have not actually provided a workable definition for whatever it is you think "effective cardinality" will be. So we are playing with nebulous concepts, and we are back to "I know it when I see it."

Comment: @J.G. Be fair to me. What I actually did is write a broken proof, *said it didn't work, and asked what could fix it*. That was the question, and it has been all along. Furthermore, the counterexamples you gave me I already solved with the discussion in Objection B, to which I directed you twice. There was no "arbitrary constraint"; it's just that the information you were giving me wasn't new. And consequently, part of the question was always: can this be fixed? Because I anticipated that this may be one of those questions which is difficult to a novice such as myself, but easy to an expert.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am afraid I still do not understand your objection. I am willing to admit that I may have not given adequate explanation, although I do believe that I am using the term "deductive closure" correctly. I'll now try to write a definition that entirely captures what I mean just  in case this is the problem. Let $S$ be a set, and $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$ a property. Let $T \subseteq S$. Then, if $T'$ is the deductive closure of $T$, I take that to mean $\rho(t)$ for all $t \in T'$ is logically determined if we know $\rho(t)$ for all $t \in T$. (1/2)

Comment: @legionwhale The problem isn't the use of the term. The problem is that any finite and any infinite sets have **different** deductive closures, and as such, given that you have examples in which you want the "effective cardinality" of a specific infinite set to be finite, if you define "effective cardinality" as "the cardinality of the smallest subset that has the same deductive closure as the set" then this definition does not agree with your explicit calculations of "effective cardinality" for specific sets. So while you have provided a definition, it does not agree with your calculations.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was referring to deductive closure with regards to only one fixed property, such as the continuity of some fixed function $f$ for the example in the question.

Comment: Then you don't have  a precise definition. What "fixed property"? An ad hoc one? Then that's not a definition. It's an energetic hand-wave. So again: you have something that **looks** like a definition, but isn't actually a definition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The continuity of the fixed function $f$. For instance, with $S$, given a sequence $(x_n) \to a$, we have the property that either $f(x_n) \to f(a)$ or $f(x_n) \not \to f(a)$. This property comes from wanting to count the number of sequences $(x_n) \to a$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am truly sorry because I do not understand. Please ask yourself why I would want to defend a broken proof, which I readily admit, even writing it in the question that it's broken, if you do not believe I am being genuine.

Comment: I am not saying you are not "genuine". I am saying you aren't listening, and I don't want to waste my time any further trying to get you to listen, because all indications are that you aren't actually interested in listening. That's not because you aren't "genuine". It's because I have better things to do than continue to repeat the same basic argument that you tell me you don't understand. I also see no reason to spend my time trying to get inside your head on this topic. Why do you want to defend a borken proof? I neither know nor care.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Saying I don't understand is hardly an argument, is it? I agree; you have better things to do. I appreciate your non-interest in wishing to "beat sense" into me, though; very diplomatic language. I don't want to defend a broken proof, I wanted to learn something but something apparently went very wrong here. That's all.

Comment: In light of your response to my last comment, I owe you another you'll find more helpful. The continuity definitions you mention are also equivalent for functions from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Q$, but $|\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}|>\Bbb Q$, so if your proof can be fixed it would need to exploit more facts about $\Bbb R$ that I suspect will make your prior steps redundant, leaving just e.g. my $\aleph_0^2$-based suggestion. Sorry I didn't bring that up sooner, but I think that's why nobody here expects a known theorem can make this work.

Comment: Note that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}_{\gt0}$ charactetizes continuity in the sense of (1) (letting $\epsilon$ range over all elements of $A$) if and only if its infimum is $0$. That means that there are countably infinite sets that suffice, but no finite one does.(Also, there is no "least"/"smallest" subset that works, even though there is a least cardinality of subsets that do). However, no countable subset of $S$ will characterize continuity in the sense of (2). The argument is hopelessly flawed both on the abstract *and* in its particular form.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "...even though there is a least cardinality of subsets that do" You now seem to understand what I mean by effective cardinality. So is it a valid definition or not? "Letting $\varepsilon$ range over all sets" I believe that this is the wrong set to consider for (1). "The argument is hopelessly flawed both on the abstract and in its particular form." Yes, you already showed earlier that the proof cannot answer the desired question and I acknowledged that. However, the concepts are still of interest to me. And apparently they still are to you, if you return to them an hour later.

Comment: I do not think you have provided a coherent general definition of a concept that is applicable to sets. With a lot of thought, I am *guessing* what you might have been (imho unsuccessfully) trying to describe for this and only this particular situation.  Which is why I said explicitly what I meant. If that idea is in fact what you were attempting to describe then do read the content of that comment to see why your attempt fails irredeemably: we can **prove** those two cardinals, which you want to claim are equal, *cannot* be equal, and one is strictly smaller than $\mathfrak{c}$ anyway.

Comment: And I did not say, as you incorrectly attribute to me in quotation marks, "letting $\epsilon$ range over all sets." If you don't take the time to even read carefully what is written, let alone try to think about it, what is the point of asking?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My apologies for misquoting. However, please also read my comments. The very last thing I can say to explain effective cardinality is that certainly it depends on both $S$ and the property $\rho$. In this case, for (2), this was that given a sequence tending to $a$ i.e. a sequence in $S$, $\rho$ is the indicator of whether $f$ applied term-wise to that sequence tends to $f(a)$. More generally, effective cardinality is a concept that would exist for any set and any property on that set. So is it not quite general?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin And to repeat myself, I am not convinced you are considering the correct set for (1). "If you don't take the time to even read carefully what is written, let alone try to think about it, what is the point of asking?" Now this is not misquoted because I have copied and pasted it, and it is quite and unnecessarily rude.

Comment: Your latest description does not capture the property I describe, which means even after I spent time trying to squeeze some sense out of your attempt, I am still unable to get anything coherent. So my answer is "no, it's still too nebulous to be a proper definition." You provpbably have a very clear idea of what you want to say. I do not believe you have actually said it.

Comment: Claiming to someone that they said something they did not say in order to say "that's wrong" is not exactly in the neighborhood of politeness. In fact, it's called a strawman argument.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Neither is almost all of your previous correspondence, and my error was unintentional. I will write a brief answer summarising what I call effective cardinality in very simple terms. If you still do not accept it, that is fine. I will either write it into a question some time or send it to some friendly academic at my university and we can have more than just our two views on the matter.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have posted the answer. I will not reply any more because there is no point. I am sure you realise that you have been more impolite than necessary (example: "I have no interest in trying to beat sense into you if you refuse to listen.") and really, I have demonstrated much more patience than was worth the effort. And I won't come back in an hour to reply yet again with more unnecessary aggravation.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is completely invalid for the reason as Arturo Magidin has noted, that it would require that the effective cardinality and cardinality of a set is always equal, for which I even gave counterexamples in the original post.

Though unlikely, however, it may be possible to say more about the effective cardinalities described in the question -- it may be possible to equate them sometimes. Since this was not treated rigorously in the body of the question, I attempt a definition below:

Let $S$ be a set. Let $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$ be a property. Then, let $T \subseteq S$. Define the deductive closure of $T$ (with respect to $\rho$) to be:

$$T' = \{t' \in S: \rho (t') \text{ can be inferred from knowing } \rho(t) \; \forall t \in T\}$$

So certainly $T \subseteq T'$. Now define the effective cardinality of $S$ to be the minimal cardinality of a set $T \subseteq S$ such that $T' = S$ (again, this depends on $\rho$, of course, which may itself depend on other parameters).

**Example 1**

Let $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$, $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed, but unknown.

$$\rho(x) = \mathbb{I}(p | x)$$

Then, the deductive closure of $\{x\}$ *contains* $\{nx : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. However, no finite set has deductive closure equal to $S$, since for any finite set, there will exist two different values of $p$ which have the same values on this set. Thus, the effective cardinality of $S$ is $\aleph_0$. (Note that the effective cardinality of a set is bounded above by its cardinality.)

**Example 2**

Let $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed (but again this does not mean known), $n \in \mathbb{N}$ known.

$$\rho(x) = \mathbb{I}(x \equiv k \text{ mod } n)$$

Then, the effective cardinality of $S$ is $n$.

**Example 3**

Let $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$,

$$\rho(x) = \mathbb{I}(x \text{ is composite})$$

Then, the deductive closure of any subset of $S$, even the empty set, is $S$ because we do not need to know ex-ante that a particular integer is prime in order to show that the composite naturals are exactly $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{2,3,...\}$ -- this can be done "from the ground up"; from the standard axioms. So $S$ has effective cardinality $0$.

**Example 4**

Let $S = \{(y_n) : y_n \to a \}$ and $\rho : S \to \{0,1\}$, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be fixed.

$$\rho(x) = \mathbb{I}(f(x) \to f(a)) $$

where $f(s)$ is the sequence obtained by applying $f$ to $x \in S$ term-wise.

Let $T \subseteq S$. Then, the deductive closure of $T$ is every sequence tending to $a$ (i.e. sequences in $S$) that consists of terms which are elements of sequences in $T$. Suppose $T$ is countable. Then, we do have that $T'$ is uncountable, but it is never the case that $T' = S$. So the effective cardinality of $S$ is $\mathfrak{c}$.

This is not necessarily true if $S = \{(y_n) : y_n \to a, y_n \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. As noted, it can be the case that a countable set has uncountable deductive closure, so the fact that $|\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}| = \mathfrak{c}$ is not necessarily an issue. It is also necessary to consider Objection A, which has not been addressed by the other answer.

---

Following from Objection A, it is clear that certain set-theoretic conditions may be required; otherwise, assuming the result, we easily obtain falsehoods such as $\mathfrak{c}= \aleph_0$ or $\mathfrak{c}=1$, which I cheerfully demonstrated myself. There must be a distinction in some way between sets, and sets which contain sets. Admittedly, this is vague, but again, I do not understand set theory.

This consideration is crucial if attempting to accurately determine the effective cardinality of a set. Without such a measure, it would be futile to carry out this argument. I have bothered to compute effective cardinalities above because the reader will retrospectively notice that in Examples 1-3, all sets $S$ had elements which do not themselves contain elements (again, forgive any set-theoretic naivety here), unlike sequences or intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, the latter of which have uncountably many elements themselves.

(And in the first part of Example 4, this only tells us further that the effective cardinality is at  least $\mathfrak{c}$, which we already know to be an upper bound. So this does not affect the conclusion that the effective cardinality is $\mathfrak{c}$.)

Thus, any true answer should first address Objection A, bearing in mind this was always the crux of the question ("can the reasoning be fixed?"). Otherwise, it will only re-tread territory already covered multiple times in the question and comments.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the general shape of the argument, it runs as follows:

> We have two sets, $R$ and $S$. We wish to show that $R$ and $S$ have the same cardinality.
>
> We find a set $A$ and a nonempty subset $B$, and properties $P$ and $Q$ such that:
>
> > 1. For all $x\in A$, $\Bigl(x\in B\iff \bigl(\forall r\in R (P(x,r))\bigr)\Bigr)$;
> > 2. For all $x\in A$, $\Bigl(x\in B\iff \bigl(\forall s\in S (Q(x,s))\bigr)\Bigr)$;
>
> both hold.
>
> We conclude that $R$ and $S$ have the same cardinality.

You seem to sketch such an argument with $A$ the set of all function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $B$ the set of functions in $A$ that are continuous at $a$, $R=\mathbb{R}_{\gt 0}$ (or some other subset of the positive reals of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$), $S$ the set of all sequences of real numbers; for $f\in A$ and $\epsilon\in R$, $P(x,\epsilon)$ is "$\exists \delta\gt 0$ such that if $|x-a|\lt \delta$ then $ |f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$"; and for $f\in A$ and $(x_n)\in S$, $Q(f,(x_n))$ is "if $x_n\to a$, then $f(x_n)\to f(a)$".

Now, as written, you acknowledge that the argument is not valid, as you can produce specific instances of $A$, $B$, $R$, $S$, $P$, and $Q$ in which the cardinalities of $R$ and $S$ are distinct. For example:

> 1. $A=\mathbb{R}$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\lt 0\}$, $R=\{0\}$, $S=[0,\infty)$, $P(x,r)="x\lt r"$, and $Q(x,s) = "x\lt s$.
> 2. $A=\mathbb{R}$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\lt 0\}$, $R=\{0\}$, $S=(0,\infty)$, $P(x,r)="x\lt r"$, and $Q(x,s)="x\lt s$".

You then suggest that perhaps the problem in those specific examples is that the sets are somehow redundant. From comments, it would seem that you would then want to define something that I interpreted as going along the following lines (I will use a different term, since I am told what I interpreted is not what was intended):

> For sets $A$, $B$, $R$ and a property $P$ such that
> $$x\in B\iff \forall r\in R (P(x,r))$$
> we say a subset $R'$ of $R$ "determines for $B$", or is an "STD" (subset that determines) if $B$ is understood from context, iff
> $$x\in B\iff \forall r\in R' (P(x,r))$$
> also holds. Define the "STD-cardinality" of $R$ (the "subset that determines") to be $\min\{ |R'|\mid R'\text{ is a subset of }R\text{ that determines for }B\}.$

(Note that we cannot talk about a "smallest subset of $R$ that determines for $B$ in general, since there may not be a least such subset; however, any nonempty set of cardinals has a least element, so we can talk about the minimum of the cardinals of all STDs).

Then the original argument would be modified as follows:

> We have two sets, $R$ and $S$. We wish to show that $R$ and $S$ have the same cardinality.
>
> We find a set $A$ and a nonempty subset $B$, and properties $P$ and $Q$ such that:
>
> > 1. For all $x\in A$, $\Bigl(x\in B\iff \bigl(\forall r\in R (P(x,r))\bigr)\Bigr)$;
> > 2. For all $x\in A$, $\Bigl(x\in B\iff \bigl(\forall s\in S (Q(x,s))\bigr)\Bigr)$;
>
> both hold.
>
> We conclude that $R$ and $S$ have the same **STD-cardinality.**

Note that the roles of $R$ and $S$ are in symmetric and interchangeable, so if we are going to replace the cardinality of $S$ with its STD-cardinality, then we must also replace the cardinality of $R$ with its STD-cardinality in the conclusion; note also that even if this particular argument held, it would not work for the instance you are trying to establish, since you are trying to conclude that $|R|=|S|$, so you would need to show that both specific sets you have are equinumerous with their STD-cardinality, which as I show below is not the case for $R$.

This also does not hold, as you yourself note, since in the case of $A=\mathbb{R}$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\lt 0\}$, $R=\{0\}$, $S=(0,\infty)$, and $P(x,r)=Q(x,r) = "x\lt r"$, the STD-cardinality of $R$ is clearly $1$, while the STD-cardinality of $S$ must be strictly larger.

So the argument cannot hold in the abstract, despite the "general idea" described as "reasonable." It may appear reasonable, but it is fallacious and does not work.

So this *general idea* just doesn't work; not in the abstract.

So perhaps, it can still be made to work in the specific instance of $A=\{f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\}$, $B=\{f\in A\mid f\text{ is continuous at }a\}$, $R=(0,\infty)$, $S$ the set of all real sequences, $P(f,r)$ being "there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $|x-a|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt r$", and $Q(f,(x_n))$ being "if $x_n\to a$ then $f(x_n)\to f(a)$". So for this and only this situation, dealing with functions in the reals.

But, no, it doesn't work in this individual instance either.

First:

**Lemma.** A subset $R'$ of $(0,\infty)$ has the property that for all $f\in A$,
$$f\in B\iff \forall r\in R'(P(f,r))$$
if and only if $\inf(R')=0$. In particular, $R'$ must be infinite, and there are countable subsets $R'$ that have the property.

*Proof.* Assume $\inf(R')=0$.

Let $f\in B$. I claim that $\forall r\in R'(P(f,r))$ if and only if $\forall r\in R(P(f,r))$. Indeed, clearly if $P(f,r)$ holds for all $r\in R$ then it holds for all $r\in R'$, since $R'\subseteq R$. Now suppose that for all $r\in R'$, $P(f,r)$ holds. Let $r\in R$. Since $\inf(R')=0\lt r$, there exists $r'\in R'$ such that $r'\lt r$. Since $P(f,r')$ holds, let $\delta\gt 0$ be such that if $|x-a|\lt\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt r'$. Then $\delta$ also suffices for $r$, since $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt r'\lt r$ holds. Thus, $P(x,r)$ holds as well. This establishes the claim.

Thus, if $\inf(R')=0$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $f\in B$;
2. $\forall r\in R (P(f,r))$
3. $\forall r\in R' (P(f,r))$.

Conversely, suppose that $\inf(R')=\epsilon_0\gt 0$. Consider the function $f$ with defined as $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq a$, and $f(a)=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$. Then $f$ is not continuous at $a$, so $f\notin B$. However, $P(f,r)$ holds for all $r\in R'$. Thus, $R'$ does not determine membership in $B$.

This establishes that a subset $R'$ of $R$ determines membership in $B$ via property $P$ if and only if $\inf(R')=0$. Since $R$ does not contain $0$, no finite subset can have infimum $0$; and the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable subset of $R$ with infimum $0$. $\Box$

So the STD-cardinality of $R$ here is $\aleph_0$. In particular, it does not equal the cardinality of $R$. This already dooms this attempt at establishing $|R|=|S|$.

On the other hand,

**Lemma.** Let $S'$ be a subset of $S$ such that for all $f\in A$,
$$f\in B\iff \forall (x_n)\in S'(Q(f,(x_n))).$$
Then $S'$ is not countable.

*Proof.* We show that for any countable subset $S'$ of $S$, there is a function $f$ that is not continuous at $a$ but for which $Q(f,(x_n))$ holds for every $(x_n)\in S'$.

Let $S'$ be a countable subset of $S$, and let $X=\{r\in\mathbb{R}\mid \exists (x_n)\in S', n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }r=x_n\}$. That is, all numbers that appear as a term in a sequence in $S'$. Now let $f$ to be the indicator function for $X\cup\{a\}$: $f(x)=1$ if $x\in X\cup\{a\}$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin X\cup\{a\}$. Note that for all $(x_n)\in S'$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x_n)=1$, and $f(a)=1$. Thus, for all $(x_n)\in S'$, we have $f(x_n)\to f(a)$, whether or not $x_n\to a$. That is, for all $(x_n)\in S'$ we have $Q(f,(x_n))$.

However, $Q(f,(x_n))$ does not hold for all $(x_n)\in S$. Indeed, define a sequence $(x_n)$ as follows: given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, pick $x_n\in (a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})\setminus X$; that is, pick a real number which is not in $X$ and is within $\frac{1}{n}$ of $a$. Such a number must exist, since $(a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})$ is uncountable, but $X$ is countable, so the difference is not empty. Thus, $(x_n)\in S$, $x_n\to a$, but $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$; however, $f(a)=1$. Hence, $Q(f,(x_n))$ does not hold. $\Box$

This means that the STD-cardinality of $S$ is strictly larger than $\aleph_0$. Using a similar argument we can show that no subset of cardinality strictly smaller than $\mathfrak{c}$ can suffice. (Since we are doing thisin order to determine the cardinality of $S$ in the first place, this is as much as we can say here). Regardless, the STD-cardinality of $R$ is not equal to the STD-cardinality of S, even though both sets characterize continuity. So the "general ideal" does not hold in the particular circumstance either, even after attempting to remove redundancies from the sets in question.

Comment: "$B=\{f\in A\mid f\text{ is continuous at }a\}$, $B=(0,\infty)$" What does this mean?

Comment: @legionwhale: Second $B$ should be an $R$.